# PHP SQL select where in array of IDs and has same variable column value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have a table kind of like the one below.

```
+----+----------+---------+
| ID | group_id | user_id |
+----+----------+---------+
|  1 |       10 |       9 |
|  2 |       20 |       8 |
|  3 |       10 |       7 |
|  4 |       10 |       6 |
|  5 |       20 |       5 |
+----+----------+---------+
```

I have an array of user IDs `[9,7,6]` and I'd like to get the Group ID where all the IDs are in the same group?

My current query:

`SELECT group_id FROM group_user WHERE user_id IN (9,7,6) GROUP BY group_id`

Bare in mind I'm not overly familiar with SQL queries.

Thanks

---

**EDIT**

I have opened a new question with more detail and my goal.

[SQL, check if conversation exists between group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36899656/sql-check-if-conversation-exists-between-group)

---

Comment: What's wrong with the query you have? It will return group ID 10. What should it return instead?

Comment: your goal is not clear. provide expected result please

Comment: Don't open a new question, clarify this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation to find group_id's which have the required user_id's associated with them.

```
SELECT group_id 
FROM group_user 
group by group_id
having sum(case when user_id IN (9,7,6) then 1 else 0 end) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(group_id) FROM group_user WHERE user_id IN (9,7,6)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT group_id 
FROM group_user 
WHERE user_id IN (9,7,6) 
GROUP BY group_id
HAVING count(DISTINCT user_id) = 3
AND count(DISTINCT group_id) = 1
```

makes sure that all 3 ids are in the same group_id and that they're not in any other group.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/540f96/2