# SQL, check if conversation exists between group

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to check if a conversation exists between an array of user IDs and then return the `conversation_id`.

**conversations** table

```
+----+---------+------------+
| ID |  name   | created_at |
+----+---------+------------+
|  1 | Group 1 | datetime   |
|  2 | Group 2 | datetime   |
+----+---------+------------+
```

**conversation_user** table

```
+----+-----------------+---------+
| ID | conversation_id | user_id |
+----+-----------------+---------+
|  1 |               1 |       9 |
|  2 |               1 |       8 |
|  3 |               1 |       7 |
|  4 |               2 |       9 |
|  5 |               2 |       6 |
+----+-----------------+---------+
```

So say I have an array of user IDs `[9,8,7]` this would return the conversation_id of `1`

And if I had an array of user IDs `[8,6]` this would return empty as the conversation doesn't exist.

But also if I had an array of user IDs `[9,7]` this would return empty because a conversation between just these two users doesn't exist either.

I've tried variances of this SQL query:

`SELECT conversation_id FROM conversation_user WHERE user_id IN (9,8,7) GROUP BY conversation_id`

I am struggling to get this query right. If anyone can help that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: @vkp Yes that question wasn't well explained so I have opened this new question to help give a better understanding of my issue and aim. Thanks.

Comment: you can edit the same question with a better explanation instead of opening a new one.you already have an answer there.